# String as variable and mapped key type behaves differently

Tags: typescript

Consider this:

```
type N = never;
type A = 'A';
type B = 'A' | 'B';
type S = string;

type RN = Record<N, string>;
type RA = Record<A, string>;
type RB = Record<B, string>;
type RS = Record<S, string>;

declare let n : N;
declare let a : A;
declare let b : B;
declare let s : S;

s = b;
b = a;
a = n;

declare let rn : RN;
declare let ra : RA;
declare let rb : RB;
declare let rs : RS;

rn = rs;
rs = rn;

rs = ra;
ra = rb;
```

Let `<` be the subtype operator. Obviously, `N < A < B < S` because `n` is assignable to `a` is assignable to `b` is assignable to `s`.

So, I would expect `RS < RB < RA < RN`.

However, from the example you see that `RB < RA < RS` because `rb` is assignable to `ra` is assignable to `rs`. Moreover, `RS` and `RN` seem to be equivalent types.

I would assume that `string` can be seen as the union type of all `string` literal types. So actually `RS` should be equal to`never` since it’s impossible to have an object with properties for all possible string literals that exist (taking infinite
space). Call this the complete object.

However it looks like `RS` is actually equivalent to the empty (`RN`) and not complete object.

Why is `string` behaving like `never` in `Record`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) map `string` and `number` [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) keys to individual properties, so `Record<"A" | "B", string>` is equivalent to `{a: string; b: string}`.

But keys of wide, non-literal types like `string` itself, or `number`, or pattern template literal types like `` `foo${string}` `` (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) are mapped to [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).   From the documentation for index signatures:

> Sometimes you don’t know all the names of a type’s properties ahead of time, but you do know the shape of the values.  In those cases you can use an index signature to describe the types of possible values.

So index signatures do not really represent "complete objects" with *all possible keys* of the relevant type, like an infinite [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all single-key objects `{a: string} & {b: string} & {c: string} & ... & {foo: string} & ... {blahblah: string} & ...`.

(Aside: you said a complete object would be equivalent to `never` because it's not possible.  But that's not really accurate.  A [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object could easily be made to conform to this type.  Even if it *were* not possible in JavaScript, it wouldn't be obvious that you'd want a type system to treat it as if it were `never`, without having some sort of explicit axiom about infinity, and then you'd have to figure out how to do that without prohibiting recursive data types.)

Anyway, index signatures are more like *constraints* on properties. An index signature of the form `{[k: IndexType]: ValType}` means "*if* the object has a property key of type `IndexType`, *then* such a property will have a value of type `ValType`".  In some sense, it's more like the infinite intersection of all single-key objects with [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), like `{a?: string} & {b?: string} & {c?: string} & ... & {foo?: string} & ... {blahblah?: string} & ...`

---

Of course it's more complicated than that, since the compiler has not traditionally treated index signatures and optional properties the same.

Before TypeScript 4.1, index signatures would always let you read properties and get a value even though I just got finished explaining how they are more like optional properties.  There were lots of complaints about this, and so TypeScript 4.1 introduced [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), which added `undefined` to the domain of index signature property values when reading, but not when writing.  It's not enabled by default, even with `--strict`, because while it's more type safe, it turns out to be annoying in any scenario where people index through arrays or objects... code like `for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {arr[i]}` or `Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k])` should technically show `arr[i]` and `obj[k]` as being possibly `undefined`, at least without having a way to track the *identity* of `i` and `k` instead of just the *type*.

Before TypeScript 4.4, optional properties were treated as having `undefined` as part of their domain both when reading *and* writing.  People complained about that a lot too, so TypeScript 4.4 introduced [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) which preserved `undefined` on reads, but rejects writing to a property with `undefined`.  This is also not included with `--strict`, since something like `foo.bar = foo.bar` is now considered an error if `bar` is optional.

If you enable both of those compiler flags, then index signatures and optional properties have similar behavior, although I'm sure more edge cases exist.

---

Anyway... `Record<string, string>` is equivalent to `{[k: string]: string}`) while `Record<never, string>` is equivalent to the [empty object type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) `{}`.  These are not identical types, but they are mutually compatible due to rules having to do with *implicit index signatures* as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#7029](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029).

There's a lot to unpack there too, and one could go on for quite a while about [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection), [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), and the interaction between index signatures and `interface` types (see [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)).  I'm going to stop now, though, since this answer is already long enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! You are right about the complete object. Of course it can exist since overriding the index getter and returning something mimics a complete object.

Answer (score 2):

> I would assume that string can be seen as the union type of all string literal types. So actually `RC` should be equal to `never` since it’s impossible to have an object with properties for all possible string literals that exist (taking infinite space).

This is the crux of the issue. A type `Record<K, V>`, and in general any type with an index signature, is supposed to mean objects whose keys are the values of the type `K`, such that if `obj: Record<K, V>` and `k: K` then `obj[k]` is of type `V`. If `K` is a type with infinitely many values, this is impossible in practice for the reason you wrote. So if we're being totally formal, then it's not possible to construct a value of type `Record<K, V>`,* so if Typescript were totally sound then `Record<string, V>`, and index signatures, would not be useful.

But Typescript is not totally sound, [nor is it meant to be](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness):

> TypeScript’s type system allows certain operations that can’t be known at compile-time to be safe. When a type system has this property, it is said to not be “sound”. The places where TypeScript allows unsound behavior were carefully considered, and throughout this document we’ll explain where these happen and the motivating scenarios behind them.

So, index signatures and `Record` work the way they do because it is useful to programmers who write Javascript code which assumes objects behave that way. Real Javascript code often uses objects as dictionaries, and often uses keys which are known to be present without handling the case where the key is not present.

For a sound alternative to `Record<string, V>`, you should write something like `{[k in string]?: V}` so that the type system explicitly knows that not all possible keys may be present in the object. In this case, when you access `obj[k]` it will have type `V | undefined` instead of `V`, and you will have to handle that possibility in your code (e.g. by narrowing with an `if` statement to check if the value is `undefined`).

---

<sup>*For technical reasons, that's not the same as `Record<K, V>` being equal to `never` when `K` is infinite. It is [semantically entailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) in the sense that those two types have the same value sets, but not [syntactically entailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Syntactic_consequence) in the sense that Typescript treats them as assignable to each other (because it doesn't). Typescript has no rule to reduce `Record<K, V>` to `never` when `K` is infinite; I don't think Typescript keeps track of whether types are infinite in the first place.</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I modified my question while you answered and added never too

Comment: I don't think the reasoning here is quite right.  `Record<K, V>` doesn't necessarily have an index signature; it's a mapped type and only has index signatures when the key type includes nonliterals like `string` or now `\`x${string}\``. Index signatures mean *if* there is a key of the index type, *then* its value has the value type.  So `{[k: string]: number}` does not mean "all `string` keys exist and have `number` values" but "for each `string` key that exists it has a `number` value".  It's almost like index signatures are *optional* properties (see `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`)

Comment: For example, `Record<"A" | "B", string>` has no index signature, so the `"A"` and `"B"` keys are required.  But `Record<string, string>` has a `string` index signature, which does not require any keys at all.  I can probably find various github issue comments by ahejlsberg and other TS team members corroborating this view of index signatures as constraints on values when keys happen to be present, if you think otherwise.

Comment: @jcalz can you point me to the typescript docs detailing that out?

Comment: The documentation for [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) says "Sometimes you don’t know all the names of a type’s properties ahead of time, but you do know the shape of the values. In those cases you can use an index signature to describe the types of possible values", so such properties are *possible* and not required.

Comment: And the documentation for [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) describes how you can opt to have index signature property reads include `undefined` for the very reason that the index signature does not imply that every possible property is actually present.  This flag is not used by default because it breaks real world code that loops through arrays or objects by index.

Comment: @jcalz okay I tried a bit and figured out together with noUncheckedIndexAccess the behavior at least becomes consistent when accessing values.

Comment: Ouch, furthermore the suggested `{[k: string]?: V}` is [invalid syntax](https://tsplay.dev/wO8O6N); there is no optional modifier for index signatures, as they are already optional (in terms of the set of keys they represent)

Comment: If @kaya3 is willing to update this answer then great, otherwise I'll probably write up my own to clear this stuff up.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, for some reason I keep forgetting that `{[k: string]?: V}` is not valid. Re: "`Record<K, V>` doesn't necessarily have an index signature", I didn't mean to imply that it does, as far as I know mapped types and index signatures are just separate things. It sounds like you understand this better than me, though, so feel free to write an answer and I expect I'll upvote it.

Comment: What l learned today: 1. Mapped types imply index signatures if the key is a non-literal-type, but literal-type keys imply required properties. 2. Index signatures are optional from the type system, but don’t widen the value type with undefined by default. But that can be enforced with noUncheckedIndexAccess. Correct @jcalz ?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  I'm happy to write up an answer but I'm not sure when I'll find the time today.

Comment: @jcalz you are always helpful when I enter the dark corners of typescript :-)